# mysql error : "cant connect to local mysql server through socket

Tags: mysql, database, heroku

i get this following error when i am trying to connect my localhost mysql to heroku postgres

```
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: Mysql::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). . .
```

any takers for this question? my OS is windows 7
thanks

Comment: Windows certainly doesn't have /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. That would be a *nix socket. You need to check your configuration and make sure it's connecting over tcp to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mysql is most likely misconfigured. A win7 box is highly unlikely to have a `/var/run` directory. So mysql is looking for its socket in the wrong place, and unable to connect.

Comment: @Cfreak , @ Marc B  what exactly i have to configure,i quiet cant get that,i am sorry i am a newbie, how do you make the local mysql not see the socket and connect over tcp?excuse me if am so amateur,thank you